# Sort iOS Photos by metadata (to remove imported WhatsApp media)

Tags: icloud, photos.app, import

Migrating from an Android phone to an iPhone, I attempted to automatically transfer camera photos across. Unfortunately, this also imported unwanted media from other applications (e.g. WhatsApp). How can I disentangle this?

Is there a way to select and group media by their camera metadata, either in *iOS Photos* or *iCloud Photos* or elsewhere?

Comment: Try this: Open Photos app on iPhone > in the bottom menu, select Albums tab > All WhatsApp media imports should be in the WhatsApp folder. You should have similar folders for other applications. Select and delete the items you don't want to keep.

Comment: @MacEater unfortunately that doesn't work. The WhatsApp album only contains any media that I *explicitly* choose to "Save" using WhatsApp on the iphone. However, *all* media that had been received with WhatsApp on the previous android phone (and that I never meant to save) is in the Recent album, intermingled with camera photos from both old and new phone.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a few basic avenues to consider.

**Native apps**

There is an Apple design philosophy of simplifying the UI by limiting the user to pre-defined actions, though internally those actions range from basic to very sophisticated. So for example, *iOS Photos* can view the basic camera metadata for a photo, and can search by visual recognition (e.g. grouping by person), but apparently cannot search by basic camera metadata. One hack is that the map (or searching by country) does provide a count of how many of the photos (or other media) *have* location metadata (which generally distinguishes camera photos from media received in WhatsApp etc), but there seems to be no functionality to "select all" or to "invert" that selection.

The *iCloud Photos* web app seems more limited than even *iOS Photos*.

The *macOS Photos* application offers some additional features, particularly "smart albums" defined by more complex customisable criteria (including various string matching rules applied to the camera metadata). It also supports "select all" (say, to delete all items in the smart album).

A potential obstacle is that using *macOS Photos* expects a computer that belongs to the same Apple ID as the phone (which can't be taken for granted, esp. since the user is migrating from non-Apple devices). Specifically, since shared albums are so limited, requires permission to add an account to a macOS computer.

**Scripting**

In principle, you could solve this problem using *iOS Photos* by inspecting the info for each item in the library individually, and on the basis of that camera information, adding the item to a corresponding album (and then potentially deleting it). It *may* be possible to automate using the *iOS Shortcuts* app, although (with lack of debugging environment) this seems at risk of creating further messes.

**Transfer**

For PC and Android, you would simply plug the phone into the computer, navigate to the folder containing the media, and apply more flexible tools.

Apple tries to treat photos (and related media) differently than ordinary files, and so the phone does not expose the photos on the filesystem that is mounted over usb. (Perhaps it is relying on being able to maintain the files in coordination with a separate database file?) It is possible to sync photos to a folder, but only if iCloud is disabled, and some metadata (including "live" photos) may be lost over round trips.